# Inform User that Touch Move Is Possible

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, user-experience

I am creating a webapp.  Within the webapp, I have a table where users can touchmove on mobile devices to select various options.

The problem I am facing is that users don't realize that that feature is available.  They just continue clicking individual options as one would normally do in a webapp.

The table that I am talking about is just a calendar in which a user can select multiple dates.  But I intend to incorporate a few other tables for other purposes as well (all with the same touchmove feature).

Has anyone faced a similar problem?  How did you get your users to realize that they could simply swipe to select multiple options without expressly providing an instruction to that affect?

Answer (score 0):

While displaying subview when your mouse was passing though interesting option on his computer, informing the mobile user about all your implemented features is quite difficult (but not impossible). There's many way to solve such issue, the following give you some suggestion:

- A common solution used by many application is `to provide a wizard` (running the first time you are launching the application for example, and available in the menu of your application) which purpose to your user to check all the features of your application by trying it... just like an assistant.
- Another solution could be to display an additional button `info` (`?`), which display some "indication" on the user screen when clicked.

There's of course many other way to perform such help for your user